# run in ubuntu 17.10 with (scd mode) published:the specified framework 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.App',version '2.1.1' was not found

Tags: .net-core

- publish enviroment:windows 10
- run enviroment:ubuntu 17.10,.netcore 2.1.2 runtime is installed
- projuect .netcore version:2.1

Before using cli command published,I added Property int the .csproj file:

```
<PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>false</PublishWithAspNetCoreTargetManifest>
```

but after published successfully, found no dependencies packages generated under the publish folder.

The same publish action with .netcore 2.0 version project,there will be some folder (eg: de,es,fr,it,ja,ko,ru) generated under publish folder.

Is there anybody know how to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry,I have fixed it by install the Microsoft.AspNetCore.App in the running machine,which only installed the Microsoft.NetCore.App before.